# Why does pip not show any installer for some packages?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

```
pip list --verbose
```

^ shows a list of every package installed in my environment, but several packages show no installer, like so:

```
Package                            Version              Location                                                                 Installer
---------------------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------
alabaster                          0.7.12               /home/jaden/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages                        conda
anaconda-client                    1.9.0                /home/jaden/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages                        conda
anaconda-navigator                 2.1.1                /home/jaden/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
anaconda-project                   0.10.1               /home/jaden/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages                        conda
anyio                              2.2.0                /home/jaden/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages                        conda
appdirs                            1.4.4                /home/jaden/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
argh                               0.26.2               /home/jaden/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
argon2-cffi                        20.1.0               /home/jaden/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages                        conda
```

Why is that? How were they installed?

Comment: The fact that you're using `pip` in an Anaconda-managed virtual environment shows us that you're mixing package managers. Did you install things into this environment using `pip`, `easy_install`, or any other non-`conda` tool? (a) That's probably what is indicated by the missing installer field. (b) _Don't do that_. Mixing installers in the same environment is a great way to bork your system.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to fix, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pip gets this information from the corresponding `.dist-info/INSTALLER` of a package. The use of a `.dist-info` folder is specified by [PEP 376](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/). Prior to this, packages followed the specification in [PEP 262](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0262/), which does not include the INSTALLER information.

Not sure about what goes in to why particular packages still use the older specification, but those that lack the `.dist-info` will show up with blank "Installer" values. That is, the blank should be read as "undetermined" rather than "not from (conda/pip)".  So, given only a `pip list --verbose` output, one cannot determine the origin for those.

Checking my own **base**, I see `conda`, `pip`, `setuptools`, and `wheel` all blank, though they are all Conda package installations for me. And this can be confirmed through `conda list`.

Comment: So, upon deletion and reinstallation, it appears that these are packages just directly installed by the system during the installation process of anaconda specified on their website.